# Encode string for URL (angular)

Tags: angular, url, encode

I'm trying to encode a string that's pretty complex, so that I can include it in a mailto:

Component:

```
<a href="mailto:test@example.com?subject='Hello'&{{body}}">
```

TS:

```
import { HttpParameterCodec } from "@angular/common/http";

let body = encodeValue('This is the example body\nIt has line breaks and bullets\n\u2022bullet one\n\u2022bullet two\n\u2022bullet three')
```

When I try to use encodeValue, I get "cannot find name encodeValue.

How would be best to url-encode body?

Comment: For a start, you can use JavaScript's [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function which should encode your text. (If you're using one of the characters - `;,/?:@&=+$#`, please use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function instead.)

Comment: That didn't work on bullets or line breaks though

Comment: It's meant to be used for URIs

Answer (score 74):

`HttpParameterCodec` : is a codec for encoding and decoding parameters in URLs( Used by HttpParams).

If you need to encode Url you can use the below:

`encodeURI` assumes that the input is a complete URI that might have some characters which need encoding in it.

`encodeURIComponent` will encode everything with special meaning, so you use it for components of URIs,  such as:

```
var textSample= "A sentence with symbols & characters that have special meaning?";
var uri = 'http://example.com/foo?hello=' + encodeURIComponent(textSample);
```

Answer (score 65):

Both encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() will work, while there are some differences:

```js
var set1 = ";,/?:@&=+$";  // Reserved Characters
var set2 = "-_.!~*'()";   // Unescaped Characters
var set3 = "#";           // Number Sign
var set4 = "ABC abc 123"; // Alphanumeric Characters + Space

console.log(encodeURI(set1)); // ;,/?:@&=+$
console.log(encodeURI(set2)); // -_.!~*'()
console.log(encodeURI(set3)); // #
console.log(encodeURI(set4)); // ABC%20abc%20123 (the space gets encoded as %20)

console.log(encodeURIComponent(set1)); // %3B%2C%2F%3F%3A%40%26%3D%2B%24
console.log(encodeURIComponent(set2)); // -_.!~*'()
console.log(encodeURIComponent(set3)); // %23
console.log(encodeURIComponent(set4)); // ABC%20abc%20123 (the space gets encoded as %20)
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent