# Encode URL Parameters in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, anchor, urlencode

I'm using Angular-9. In a Grid, I'm building a Link as below:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/assortmentplanning/planmanagement/open-plan', data.name, data.channelName]">
   {{data.name}}
</a>
```

I want to Encode the URL Parameters and Decode in receiving Component. How to do this in Angular?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420376/encode-string-for-url-angular here are some hints which may point you into the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode string for URL (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420376/encode-string-for-url-angular)

Comment: @R.Richards No.. It's not working for me.