# Query parameter getting stripped when combination of "code"&"state" in angular app

Tags: angular

I have an angular app which is connecting to a server and getting a redirect URL with query parameters **"Code&State"**

Problem:

The query parameters are getting stripped at the time of redirecting to the URL.
I observed that the stripping of parameters is happening only when the URL contains both **code & state**
as query parameters. If I change any of the parameters it is working as expected(query parameters are not stripped).

Below is my route configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
]
```

URL : https://localhost:4200?code=1234&state=12365

I tried with below query parameter combination it's working fine

URL : https://localhost:4200?code=1234&id=12365

URL : https://localhost:4200?code=1234&statee=12365

URL : https://localhost:4200?state=1234&id=12365

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420376/encode-string-for-url-angular

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in my code,

I get this problem because of using **auth0** in my application I get this problem.

I Resolved this issue, By taking new application with same code with out using **auth0** it's working fine.

Thank you....