# Angular 17, possible encode http params on the fly?

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have an application with quite a few inputs already. When the user enters a special character like an `&` it results in an API error. Which makes sense given what's being set is something like:

`name=bob&title=employee&number=&45`

Where `number` triggers the error. I assumed Angular encoded things like that on it's own but I assumed wrong I guess. I can write a directive to prevent the user from entering specific characters but I'd rather just let them do it and encode special characters.

I thought about grabbing things at an interceptor, encoding, and reconstructing the call but that might be overkill.

Is there a more official or efficient way to encode params on the http call prior to the api request?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for urlencode - some background info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420376/encode-string-for-url-angular) - not an exact dupe, I don't think.

Comment: How do you create your URL's? I would bet that HttpParams does this already....

Comment: @Antoniossss currently they get setup by constructing the url like `name=${name}&title=${titleType}&number=${numberValue}`

Comment: I just use a replace... something like: your_input.replace('/', '%2F').replace('#', '%23').replace('&', '%26') should do it.  I only need that when creating links to other sites though... when using location.assign('#/page?' + queryParams); the URL encoding is done automatically.  Are you using HttpParams()?

Comment: Use proper tools to do the job https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams