# Routing encoded url in angular

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, url-routing, urlencode

In my angular project i have a route as a

```
  path: 'friend/messages/:encryptedKey/:type',
  component: EncryptedRouteComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
,
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent,
```

if i hit url as

```
baseUrl/friend/messages/NjgzMw==/inbox
```

i am navigating to PageNotFoundComponent component
and there i gets url as only

```
baseurl/friend/messages/NjgzMw
```

thats why its not going to EncryptedRouteComponent
how to fix this

this is my code snippet of PageNotFoundComponent

in PagenotFoundComponent i want decoded url as

```
friend/messages/NjgzMw/inbox
```

so that i will successfully navigate to EncryptedRouteComponent

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the scenario in stackblitz, but you can use `encodeURI` or `decodeURI` to pass the keys if you have problems parsing them normally!

You can also use `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` for this!

[reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420376/encode-string-for-url-angular)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, provideRouter, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'zone.js';
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'test/:id/qwerty',
    component: TestComponent,
  },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const encoded = encodeURI('NjgzMw==');
    this.router.navigate(['test', encoded, 'qwerty']);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
});
```

child

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  value = '';
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.value = decodeURI(params['id']);
    });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bowxzv?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts,src%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter)